# How to avoid APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase for particular event

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have a requirement wherein the form displays many input fields from model object.

And on one of the fields an external plugin is invoked and the value of that field is directly changed in the model by that plugin (not changed in UI form field), now I would like to reRender that panel so that changed value (from model object) is displayed onto UI form field.

Verified everything and plugin is also able to change value in the model and its also triggering reRender of the panel. When reRender, what happens is the values in UI form are applied to model and model object loses the value (set by plugin) and when panel is refreshed I would still see blank Field.

Is there a way that only for this event I bypass APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES so that values in model are displayed? Or is there a better solution for this?

Regards,
Satya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `immediate="true"` for this.

```
<a4j:support ... immediate="true" />
```

This way only the current component will be processed.

Another way is to just proceed to render response immediately in the value change listener so that the Update Model Values (and Invoke Action) phase is skipped.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
```